# Mpeg-dash mpd file through REST request

Tags: mpeg-dash

My system requires a live mpeg dash stream,as well as a unique mpd file on each request. I've tried setting up the server with REST and websockets but neither seem to be recognised with dashjs player. Only if I reload the page, loading the mpd file directly (ie not as a response to the request itself).

I'm sure this is because i'm lacking some basic understand of http requests and websockets, but maybe someone can put me in the right direction?

Comment: Is the MPD@type attribute set to "live" and does the manifest contain the MPD@minimumUpdatePeriod attribute? Which values does the @minimumUpdatePeriod have? Maybe the manifest and/or your existing code could help.

Comment: I'm using [Casablanca](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) to create the REST server